# Application stop responding when I change permission from app settings in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location

I am using location tracking in my application, all working fine. But when I push my app in background by pressing home button, revoke location permission from application settings and come back to my application it stop responding & get crash.
I am using Service for location tracking.
It also stops debugging when I change permission from settings.

please tell me how can I handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The marshmallow and above version use different setup for requesting permissions. You need to setup it

then if your application doesnot have the required permission it would ask for it on runtime.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

it may help you!

Comment: if you did not get that then don't hesitate to comment and also don't forget to up vote the answer :)

Comment: I have already done this
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
{
 if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
 {
  String perm[] = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
  requestPermissions(perm, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}

Comment: then you may edit your question and post your logcat errors, to dig deep!

Answer (score 0):

onRestart() --> onStart() --> onResume() is called when you come back from settings and the app becomes visible to the user so we need to check again whether the permission has been granted or not in onRestart() method. If the permission is not granted you need to show permission dialog again. Hope this helps!!

Comment: I have already done this in onResume(). If permission is not granted, it will ask for permission first